# Symfony 6.3 Class "App\Service\DeclarationService" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having an application on Symfony 6.3.

I've created a Service, but I've always the error "Class "App\Service\DeclarationService" does not exist".
I don't understand where is the mistake.

DeclarationController :

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Service\DeclarationService;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DeclarationController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'app_declaration')]
    public function index(DeclarationService $declarationService): Response {
        $annees = $declarationService->createYearsArray();
       
        return $this->render('declaration/index.html.twig', [
            'annees' => $annees,
        ]);
    }
}
```

DeclarationService :

```
namespace App\Service;

class DeclarationService
{
    public function createYearsArray(): array
    {
        $dateArray = [];
        for ($i=0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
            $dateArray[] = date('Y', strtotime('-'.$i.' years'));
        }
        sort($dateArray);

        return $dateArray;
    }
}
```

services.yaml :

```
parameters:
    domain_name: '%env(DOMAIN_NAME)%'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        bind:
            $domainName: '%domain_name%'
    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
```

tree of the app :

```
├─ assets/
├─ bin/
│  ├─ console/
│  └─ phpunit
├─ config/
│  ├─ packages/
│  ├─ routes/
│  ├─ bundles.php
│  ├─ preload.php
│  ├─ routes.yaml
│  └─ services.yaml
├─ migrations/
├─ public/
│  ├─ translations/
│  └─ index.php
├─ src/
│  ├─ Kernel.php
│  ├─ Controller/
│  ├─ Entity/
│  ├─ Form/
│  ├─ Repository/
│  └─ Service/
├─ templates/
├─ tests/
├─ translations/
├─ var/
│  ├─ cache/
│  └─ log/
└─ vendor/
```

Any suggestion is welcomed.

I've cleared the cache. I've tried `composer dump-autoload`, but the error is persisting.
I've created the project with the composer command create-project (just as explained in the official documentation).
I've some others Symfony projects, but none of them has made such an error. I'm confused....

Comment: Please clear the Symfony Cache and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your file name (DeclarationService.php instead of DeclarationService)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35670007)

Answer (score 1):

Configuration looks right, maybe you have outdated autoloader mapping or cache.

Try running `composer dump-autoload` and `symfony console cache:clear`.

If this does not help, try providing us with the folder structure of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone. It was a stupid mistake : my DeclarationService had not its extension in the name (DeclarationService instead of DeclarationService.php).
I'm using for the first time Visual Studio Code, in place of PhpStorm. I'm used to have everything done by PhpStorm...